# Passing a enum into a constructor in Java

Tags: java

I am learning java. I would like to have a enum as a parameter in my constructor. But I am getting an error
(I have my enum in a separate class that is public and named AvailabilityState {AVAILABLE,ORDERED,REMOVED }

```
public class Facultymember extends User {
private  int MAX_GENERALBOOKS = 5;
private  int MAX_AUDIOBOOKS = 2;
private AvailabilityState aStatus;

public Facultymember(int genbook, int audbook,AvailabilityState aStatus ){
        this.MAX_GENERALBOOKS=genbook;
        this.MAX_AUDIOBOOKS=audbook;
                this.aStatus  = aStatus;
    }



@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Facultymember {" + "MAX_GENERALBOOKS=" + MAX_GENERALBOOKS+ ",  MAX_AUDIOBOOKS =" +  MAX_AUDIOBOOKS  + "AvailabilityState," + aStatus +  '}';
    }

}**
```

Comment: Please include the error message and the line where it occurs.

Comment: @4everMe That constructor call doesn't have an AvailabilityState as you defined the constructor to require. Make a different constructor with default AvailabilityState, or provide one in the constructor call.

Comment: @4everMe . You're calling the constructor with two parameters (`genbook` and `audbook`), but the constructor that you've defined requires *three* parameters (`genbook`, `audbook`, and `aStatus`).  Either pass in the correct number of arguments to the constructor, or create a separate constructor that only needs `genbook` and `audbook` if that's a valid approach for your code.

Comment: constructor facultymember in class facultymember cannot be applied to given types

Comment: constructor facultymember in class facultymember cannot be applied to given types User facultymember = new Facultymember(5,2);

Answer (score 1):

If you require a parameter of type AvailabilityState, you should provide it, like so:

```
User availableFaculty = new Facultymember(5,2, AvailabilityState.AVAILABLE);
User orderedFaculty = new Facultymember(5,2, AvailabilityState.ORDERED);
User removedFaculty = new Facultymember(5,2, AvailabilityState.REMOVED);
```

Alternatively, define another constructor with default availability state:

```
public Facultymember(int genbook, int audbook) {
    // assuming availability by default
    this(genbook, audbook, AvailabilityState.AVAILABLE);
}
```